# Having trouble with undefined output from this code below

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzbuzz() {
  while (count <= 100) {
    if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
      output.push("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (count % 5 === 0) {
      output.push("Buzz");
    } else if (count % 3 === 0) {
      output.push("Fizz");
    } else {
      output.push(count);
    }
    count++;
  }


  console.log(output);
}
```

## the output from the google chrome and Mozilla Firefox inspector page, says output is  not defined.

## Seriously, don't know why.

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: Are you _running_ the `fizzbuzz` function, or only looking at the output when you enter the definition into the console? The result of any statement will simply print "undefined" in the FireFox inspector console. Typing `fizzbuzz()` should have the result you expect.

Answer (score 2):

The `undefined` you're seeing isn't what's being logged in your `console.log` statement; your function hasn't been run yet, it's only being *defined*. The `undefined` is the value of the *expression* you're evaluating in the console, which isn't really relevant.

Simply add a `fizzbuzz()` statement to run your function and you'll see the expected output logged.

Comment: Thank you @Jacob

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzbuzz() {
while (count <= 100) {
  if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
    output.push("FizzBuzz");
  } else if (count % 5 === 0) {
    output.push("Buzz");
  } else if (count % 3 === 0) {
    output.push("Fizz");
  } else {
    output.push(count);
  }
  count++;
}
console.log(output);
}
// just need to add the below line
fizzbuzz();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a modified snippet of your function:
1) i moved your var declarations into the function scope instead of being global so that other functions cant influence their values
    a) consider a for loop instead of a while loop. a for loop is more aligned to the purpose of doing something for a predetermined count such as count < 100
2) changed your console.log to a return statement so that when this function is called it will perform its calcs and send back the data. thus it doesnt require the caller to have access to a console (ie called from an alert, document.write, etc)
3) called your function from inside a console.log statement so that the return value will be logged as was your original desire

```js
function fizzbuzz() {
  var output = [];
  var count = 1;
  while (count <= 100) {
    if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
      output.push("FizzBuzz");
    } else if (count % 5 === 0) {
      output.push("Buzz");
    } else if (count % 3 === 0) {
      output.push("Fizz");
    } else {
      output.push(count);
    }
    count++;
  }
  return output;
}
console.log(fizzbuzz());
```

Comment: You should explain why you've made those changes, it may not be clear to a beginner.

Comment: @DaCurse thanks for the feedback. i have attempted to make it clearer but fear i may have simply made it wordier.

Answer (score 0):

```
function FizzBuzz() {
    var output = [];
    var count = 1;
    while (count <= 100) {
        if (count % 3 === 0 && count % 5 === 0) {
            output.push("FizzBuzz");
        } else if (count % 3 === 0) {
            output.push("Fizz");
        } else if (count % 5 === 0) {
            output.push("Buzz");
        } else {
            output.push(count);
        }
        count++;
    }
    return output;
}
console.log(FizzBuzz());
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.